# Polyurethane Acoustic Foam Procedural Texture

Tags: texturing

I'm looking for some suggestions on the best way to procedurally generate an acoustic foam material. The material has small flecks of glitter in it and I'm struggling to replicate this specifically. Sorry that the image is a little compressed, this is the [acoustic foam](https://www.foamdirect.co.uk/acoustic-foam-sound-proofing/) I'm working from, so I would like to get as close to this as possible. Thank you.
[image: Acoustic Foam]

Comment: This looks like a Cycles noise node as the base.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?